# Unable to execute code on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have been watching tutorials on data mining using python. I have installed Anaconda Python 3.5 package for windows 64 bit with default installation. I have made the program available to all users on my laptop. I am running windows 10 64 bit. I am able to open Jupyter notebook on localhost at  http://localhost:8888 and browse to the folder than contains iPython notebook file. I can type commands in the text box but could not execute them. I don't know if this can be fixed by changing the current configuration. I have attached two screenshots for references. It is weird that the play button is missing. Instead a next button is shown at the same place. It will be greatly appreciated if someone could walk me through the steps. I do not know how to generate logs for debugging. But I am willing to try. Thanks everyone!

[image]

Comment: If you've used older versions, the icon for the 'run cell' button changed from 'play' to 'step forwards' (triangle pointing right, vertical line). You can also run cells by pressing shift-enter.

Answer (score 0):

The info here http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Notebook/Running%20Code.html says try `shift+enter` or green rectangle button. Would it not be easier to just save the file and run it from terminal with `python (file)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try the "Cell" dropdown and "Run all" or while in the cell (the side highlight would be green), do `shift + enter` at same time.

Ipython has two modes: One to edit/run. Another to navigate.

Comment: if the answer works, please consider accepting it, you could also upvote.